anyone knows how to use CPI to transfer from a pda to a normal account(just has it pubkey),btw by using Anchor
it's my transfer code, but of course it goes error.
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct random<'info>{
  #[account(
      mut,
      has_one = pubkey!(HqqNdVUmtcrJADTz3mKvJrn6cCXgxAaq15nsdRZnpnko)
    )]
    pub donut_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

let transfer_fee_sol_cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            system_program::Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.buyer.to_account_info(),
                to: donut_account_info,
            },
        );
        system_program::transfer(transfer_fee_sol_cpi_ctx, donut_fee_lamports)?;

I emited the other account in the Accounts, fox example buyer..., anyone can help me?

I don't wanna donut_account_info as a signer

If you have authority over donut_account_info account
you can
ctx.accounts.buyer.sub_lamports(amount)?;
ctx.accounts.donut_account_info.add_lamports(amount)?;

P.S: It's not possible to make transfers in anchor using only the public key, you need to specify this account in the #[derive(Accounts)] context

how I specify it. just like I do?
 #[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct random<'info>{
  #[account(
      mut,
      has_one = pubkey!(HqqNdVUmtcrJADTz3mKvJrn6cCXgxAaq15nsdRZnpnko)
    )]
    pub donut_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}
``` but it goes error

could you open up a new question with the error you are getting together with the code snippet causing it
